# Tricky transition in custom view

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

Good day everyone!

A customer asked me to implement a view. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtj3l11k12inj80/scrolling.mp4?dl=0) you can download and look at video how this view should work. (Left cells are days, right - hours)
It's kind of calendar view. 
I've tried to do this task with collection view and custom layout. But do not hit much success. Because of the tricky transition of left cells. They become smaller (to speed up scroll), but right side is still the same.

Is there any possibilities to create such transition in collection view or picker view? Or should i use base view with overriding draw method?

Regards, Eugene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a calendar, so it's essentially infinite, so I don't think a UICollectionView or UITableView is appropriate for this (e.g. what would you return as the number of cells?).

I'd be creating custom UIView subclasses for the left and right side, and overriding drawRect.

Comment: I guess you are right. I had not thought about it. Thank you